# Call server side class from standalone .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an application which generates standalone aspx pages these pages has their own `script` in c#.

Now I don't want to add all the c# scripting code into the c# `script` tag so I want to call a backend c# class which will contain all the scripting code(which is normal c# code).
I want to call that backend c# class from this script i.e.

```
<script language="CS" runat="server"> 
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();// backend class
myclass.GetAllScripts(); //say this is the fucntion which contains scripting 
code
</script>
```

Comment: Is this `MVC` project or  `Web Forms` project ?

Comment: This is a `MVC` project

Comment: Why would you have .aspx-page in MVC-project? It does not make sense? Please elaborate your problem and create [mcve]. With this little information it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @Esko I have edited the question please have a look.

Comment: Still very unclear and incomplete. C# only runs on the server so calling it 'script' only obfuscates. And what is the desired result?

Comment: The code sample I have just posted here is a front-end code. C# provides you the feature to write backend code in yours .aspx files. All I want is a way to call a backend class instead of writing that code in the frontend file. Hope it is clear now?

Comment: As you said, that code will be executed on the server side, so any public class or method can be called from that code. Why you are unable to do that is beyond the code you posted here. Are you using the proper namespaces? Is the class public? I can only guess.

Comment: Right now I have different functions written in plain c# in mine .aspx page and they are working properly. But I want to move those functions into a separate class say MyClass.cs and all I will have to do is to call that class and its functions from my frontend .aspx page.

Comment: Do I understand that this code is generated dynamically at runtime? You would have to compile it into a dll, like with csc.exe. Sounds very insecure though.

Comment: Yes, the code is generated dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You could save the generated code in the `App_Code` folder, codes in this folder will be compiled at runtime and ready for the other parts of the application

E.g.:

```
var generatedCode = 
@"
    namespace MyProject
    {
        public class MyClass
        {
            public void GetAllScripts()
            {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
";
var generatedPage = 
@"
    <%@ Page Language=""C#"" AutoEventWireup=""true"" %>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script language=""CS"" runat=""server"" >
            void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //below code will be executed when the page is opened
                MyClass myclass = new MyClass();// backend class
                myclass.GetAllScripts();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
    </html>
";

// change to the path and file name to fit your need, but the cs file must in ~/App_Code
var aspxPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), "GeneratedPage.aspx");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(aspxPath, generatedPage);

var csPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Code"), "MyClass.cs");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(csPath, generatedCode);
```

Comment: Where do I have to place this sample of code in my aspx page?

Comment: In the place where you generated the standalone aspx pages

Comment: I need to call this `<%=MyProject.MyClass.SomeMethod() %>` in my `<script Language = CS runat=sever>`

Comment: This is only true for web site -applications, which in my opinion should not be used at all anymore. You should always use web application, does not matter of it's Asp.Net Web Forms or Asp.Net Mvc. In web application -project all of the folders will be build so the App_code-folder is irrelevant.